# Trying to list movies on my database in an embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

It works when i console.log the result[0], but don't add into my embed

```
var usuarioDB = new Discord.User();
          usuarioDB = message.author;
          // Añadir Clave primaria y campo único
          var row = 0;
          var sql = 'SELECT count(id_estado) as NºFilas from estado;';
          pool.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            var TotalRows = result[0].NºFilas - 1;
            const PelisLista = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("Peliculas Pendientes")
            .setColor(`${cfg.color}`);
            for (row = 0; row < TotalRows; row++) {
              var SQLIST = `SELECT Nombre_Pelicula, FechaAdición from peliculas join estado on estado.id_pelicula = peliculas.id_pelicula where estado like 'Pendiente' order by Nombre_Pelicula desc LIMIT ${row}, 1;`;
              pool.query(SQLIST, function (err, resultPelis) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("\nListing Movies\n\n");
                console.log(resultPelis[0].Nombre_Pelicula);
                console.log(resultPelis[0].FechaAdición);
                PelisLista.addField(':cinema:', `${resultPelis[0].Nombre_Pelicula}`, true)
                PelisLista.addField(':date:', `${resultPelis[0].FechaAdición}`)
                PelisLista.addBlankField()
              });
            }
            PelisLista.addBlankField();
            message.channel.send(PelisLista);
          })
```

EDIT: I solved it, changed te way to do it

```
var usuarioDB = new Discord.User();

        const PelisLista = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle("Peliculas Pendientes")
          .setColor(`${cfg.color}`);
        var SQLIST = `SELECT Nombre_Pelicula, FechaAdición, estado from peliculas join estado on estado.id_pelicula = peliculas.id_pelicula where estado like 'Pendiente' or estado like 'Viendo' order by Nombre_Pelicula;`;
        pool.query(SQLIST, function (err, resultPelis) {
          if (err) throw err;
          resultPelis.forEach(element => {
            console.log("\nListing Movies\n\n");
            if (element.estado === 'Pendiente') {
              PelisLista.addField(`${element.Nombre_Pelicula}`, `${element.FechaAdición}`);
            } else {
              PelisLista.addField(`${element.Nombre_Pelicula} *(Seleccionada)*`, `${element.FechaAdición}`);
            }
            
          });  //(entry => {});
          message.channel.send(PelisLista);
        });
```

The code above returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NMeq.png) embed. But logs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX1xA.png) in console

Have to say that i'm so new to programming, more to discord.js.
Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is about, but try to change NºFilas for No_Filas, since some editors have problems with non-letters symbols.

Comment: Just tried what you said and it stills the same, btw what i want this code to do, is list all the movies in my database 1 by 1, to do it, i'm doing a query to get the No of rows it return, and pass it to the 'for', that do the query 1 by 1 incrementing the row number and adding those 3 fields. But it prints only de field outside the 'for'